# Proof by contradidction that the mean of a set cannot be greater than the greatest value in that set.

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, means

I want to prove that given a set of values $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, the mean of those values cannot be greater than the greatest of those values.

Let the mean $\frac{x_1 + x_2 +... + x_n}{n} = a$

Assume that $a > x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ and let $x_1 + x_2 +... + x_n = b$

Then $b < a \cdot n$

Therefore $\frac{b}{n} < \frac{a \cdot n}{n}$, so that $\frac{b}{n} < a$

But since by definition $\frac{b}{n} = a$, this is a contradction.

QED(?)

Comment: Looks good. QED indeed.

Comment: @A.Sh "QED indeed" :D Thank you!

Comment: @Henrik That $b/n=a$ follows by the definitions of $a$ and $b$, so its technically there.

Comment: @Henrik, sorry I"m not sure I understand. I'm not saying that the definition of $b$ is $\frac{b}{n}$; I'm saying that by definition, the mean is $\frac{b}{n}$ and that it's supposed to be equal to $a$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is a "fake" proof by contradiction ,ie you don't need to assume something is false to run the proof.

You are just saying

$x_1 + ... x_n \leq n (\max\{x_1,...,x_n\}) $

Comment: Indeed I do not understand why none of the comments pointed it out...

Comment: The OP wanted to make a proof by contradiction. He has done so. No need to argue whether you _can_ make a proof without using the specific proof technique here…

Comment: Perhaps in some formal sense it is proof by contradiction, but it seems relevant that this isn't how "proof by contradiction" is used in practice. It is most appropriate when the assumption actually gives you something extra to work with.